# WinInet and SessionCookies

Tags: cookies, session-cookies, wininet

Hello and good evening to all.

I have my app that uses InternetSetCookie to create (session) cookies needed for its job. However I want to remove the cookie named for ex. 'badcookie' after each request via

InternetSetCookie("http://www.domain.com",  "badcookie", "");
and
InternetSetCookie("http://www.domain.com",  NULL, "badcookie=")

but...in best case it will send cookie w/o any value and thats that.

**My question is how to completly remove this cookie?**
(No, I dont want to make them permanent and call cleanup() 10 times, maybe I would create thread for each request but its akward if I do it)

Comment: I don't know WinINET API, but just expire the cookie.  I'd add this as an answer, but I don't know the syntax for doing this.  That's how you'd do it in ASP.NET.  Set the expiration date to a date in the past and the cookie will be deleted on the client.

Comment: ^ This works for cookies my app has created, but I just dropped cookie of same name via IE and thus I send two 'badcookie's and only one can be deleted this way. I suggest setting epoch time as expiry. However this is a propper hax, so maybe there is some other solution and I will leave this opened :). Thanks David and don't worry I will add solution in ur name ;) but maybe there are others!

Comment: Glad I could be of some help.  I put my comment in as an answer in case it helps down the road.  Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

InternetSetCookie("http://domain.com",  NULL,  "badcookie=bye; expires = Sat,01-Jan-1970 00:00:00 GMT");

This removed the complete txt file with some other cookies inside. Before I was using www.domain.com and I saw that it was problem... now I face same issue as the link you posted (lossing more cookies) but my question is answered now.

PS This works with session cookies too.

Answer (score 0):

My answer isn't 100% complete, but maybe it's a start.  I'd suggest setting the expiration of the cookie to be in the past, as this will force the client to clear the cookie.  I'm not familiar with WinINET syntax, so maybe someone has a better answer.  I'm more of an ASP.NET person - but this [article](http://www.ms-news.net/f1859/must-i-use-a-path-to-clear-cookies-with-internetsetcookie-7916834.html) seems to suggest how to expire the cookie.

Based on gaor's response to my initial comment, sounds like there's still a little more work to do to completely fix this.  But hopefully this helps and gets someone pointed in the right direction.

Hope this helps!